# Exclude folder/file from atom's view

Tags: atom-editor

Can I exclude a file pattern that includes its parent directories in atom? For example, I want to exclude folder1/folder2/*.py. Also I don't want to put this into .gitignore, because the git repository is shared with others and only I don't care about those files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages available that let you keep an `.atomignore` file for exactly that purpose, e.g. [tree-ignore](https://atom.io/packages/tree-ignore) or [atom-ignore](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ignore) packages.